# Id of newly added Entity before SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am adding an entity to my database like so:

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
{
     return (TEntity)_database.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
}
```

However, the `DbSet.Add` method isn't returning the newly added entity with the Id etc, it is simply returning the object I passed in to my `Add` method.

Should it be passing me back the complete new entity including `Id`, or is it not possible to get the `Id` before `SaveChanges()` is called?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the call to `Add()` is doing is effectively registering it with the data context so that the entity can be tracked. No actual operation is done against the database at this time until (as you rightly mention) you call `SaveChanges()`.

I'm assuming that you're using automatically-generated Ids in your table; in this case, it's the database engine which will generate that Id when the record is inserted, and Entity Framework will read this back and populate your entity for you.

So, to confirm your suspicions, no - it's not possible to get the Id before `SaveChanges()` is called in this case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: cheers, I thought that must be it, annoying in respect to my current problem but it makes sense

Comment: If you are able to switch primary key types, you could use GUID's and generate them your .net code before sending to the DB.