# What's the return value of DBSet.Add(object o)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Consider the situation.
I have a userlogin table. the userlogin has the following fields.
  `userid(identity(1,1))`, `username(unique)`, `password(string)`
I have another table, userRole with following fields.
`userid(fk referencing userlogin)`, `role(string)`

Now suppose I want to add an admin user to my empty application database.
What I am currently doing is:

```
// Check Userlogin if it contains adminuser1 as username, if not, add adminuser1 with password xyz. 

UserLogin login = new UserLogin();  
login.username = "adminuser1";  
login.password = "xyz";  
context.UserLogins.Add(login);  
context.SaveChanges();  

// query again from database to get the userid   
Userlogin user = context.UserLogins.Single(l => (l.username == "adminuser1") && (l.password == "xyz"));  
int userid = user.userid;  
UserRole admin = new UserRole();  
admin.userid = userid;  
admin.role = "admin";  
context.UserRoles.Add(admin);  
context.SaveChanges();
```

I want to make it a less troublesome, if we can get the userid of userRecently Added, without making another request.

I mean I want to do this if it is possible.

```
UserLogin login = new UserLogin();  
login.username = "adminuser1";  
login.password = "xyz";  
UserLogin user = context.UserLogins.Add(login);  
UserRole admin = new UserRole();  
admin.userid = user.userid;  
admin.role = "admin";  
context.UserRoles.Add(admin);  
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Update**

I also wanted to know if there is some way to do
`context.UserLogins.Single(l => l == login);`
instead of

```
context.UserLogins.Single(l => (l.username == "adminuser1") && (l.password=="xyz"));
```

because I use the same method in large classes in many fields.

Comment: kindly have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523568/entity-framework-retrieve-id-before-savechanges-inside-a-transaction

Comment: Thanks, but I also wanted to know if there is some way to do context.UserLogins.Single(l=>l==login);   instead of  context.UserLogins.Single(l=>(l.username=="adminuser1")&& (l.password=="xyz"));...because, I use the same method in large classes with many fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question

> What's the return value of DBSet.Add(object o)

The answer is: it will return the same `object o`(i.e. without the userid). Simply because `userid` is an `identity` column and relies on the database, its value is only available after `context.SaveChanges()` is called. Since `Add()` method only registers that a change will take place after `SaveChanges()` is called.

For the answer to update,
Instead of using

```
context.UserLogins.Single(l => (l.username == "adminuser1") && (l.password=="xyz"));
```

For classes that have many fields, I can check if there are any unique columns. For example. I could use, simply

```
context.UserLogins.Single(l => l.username == "adminuser1");
```

Just because, `username(unique)` is specified in the question.

I would rather recommend people use a single `Stored Procedure`. The calling of `context.SaveChanges()` and the `context.xyz.Single()` require opening database connection multiple times. For optimising performance you can use Stored Procedures, as they require only one connection per task. For more information.

[Understang Performance Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/performance-considerations)

As I am using database first approach, I found this link also helpful.

[Use Stored Procedure in Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be different based on your needs but you can have something like:

```
public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
}

public class UserLogin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public UserRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

and then use them like:

```
var login = new UserLogin
{
    username = "adminuser1",
    password = "xyz"
};
var admin = context.UserRoles.Single(_=> _.role == "admin");
if (admin == null)
{
    admin = new UserRole
    {
        role = "admin"
    };
}
login.Role = admin;  
context.UserLogins.Add(login);  
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The database is pre-generated, and I don't want to change it. The UserRole userid is a foreign key and must reference a primary key(userid identity(1,1) in UserLogin).

Comment: OK, wait for my new answer

Comment: Please see my updated question, if you can help in this respect also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Your models' relationship seems wrong but based on your information you can have this:**

```
var login = context.UserLogins.Single(_ => _.username == "adminuser1");
if (login == null)
{
  login = new UserLogin();
  login.username = "adminuser1";  
  login.password = "xyz";
  context.UserLogins.Add(login); 
  context.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
   // this user already exists.
}

var admin = context.UserRoles.Single(_ => _.role == "admin");
if (admin == null)
{
  admin.userid = login.userid;  
  admin.role = "admin"; 
  context.UserRoles.Add(admin);  
  context.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
  // the role already exists.
}
```

`context.UserLogins.Single(l => l == login);` would not work for you! you have to query DB based on your model key, not whole model data!

Comment: lets say a situation with your code that "adminuser1" doesnot exist. Then the code inside if statement executes, after making changes to the database, the login variable is still null while you try to access its property login.userid

Comment: further, same userlogin can have different roles, that's why I think the database is correct. However, I am using design model from database, so there is no point in getting a wrong model as long as database is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193873/discussion-between-pradeep-singh-and-majid-parvin).

Comment: Thanks @Majid for updating the question and your efforts in the answers. However, I found my own answer could satisfy me.